# How to draw multiple points on imageview in android java

Tags: java, android, canvas, firebase-mlkit

I'm setting up an eye detection android project and I want to draw probabilities using Canvas, I'm using Firebase ML kit for custom models
I have successfully drawn only one point.
I would like to draw points ( probabilities from tflite model that I have ).

I tried using those functions :

```
private void useInferenceResult(float[] probabilities) throws IOException {

    // [START mlkit_use_inference_result]
    String[] result=new String[80];
    float x=0;
    float y=0;
    ArrayList<Point> listpoint= new ArrayList<Point>();

    for (int i = 0; i < probabilities.length; i++) {

        Log.i("MLKit", String.format("%1.4f", probabilities[i]));
        x=probabilities[i];
        y=probabilities[i+1];
        Point p=new Point(x,y);
        i=i+1;

        p.setX(x);
        p.setY(y);

        Log.i("Information1 ","valeur 1 "+p.getX());

        listpoint.add(p);
            Log.i("Information2 ","valeur 2 "+p.getX());
    }

    for(int j=0;j<listpoint.size();j++){

        Log.e("Information","work");
        Log.e("Resultat","point_"+j+"("+listpoint.get(j).getX()+", "+listpoint.get(j).getY()+")");
        float xx=listpoint.get(j).getX()*100;
        float yy=listpoint.get(j).getY()*100;
        drawpoint(image2,0.20958422f * 100,0.6274962f * 100,1);
        drawpoint(image2, 0.20460524f * 100,0.6708223f * 100,1);

    }
}

//drawpoint function
private void drawpoint(ImageView imageView,float x,float y, int raduis){

    BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    myOptions.inDither = true;
    myOptions.inScaled = false;
    myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// important
    myOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imgg,myOptions);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
    canvas.drawCircle(x,y, raduis, paint);

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
}
```

but I didn't get any result just one point drawn.
How can I draw multiples points on imageView?

Comment: If you remove code comments it is more likely you get help

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing some lines of code, I declare those variables on the top and I create objects after setContentView:

```
BitmapFactory.Options myOptions;
Canvas canvas;
Bitmap mutableBitmap;
Bitmap workingBitmap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn_open= findViewById(R.id.btn_open);
    image2= findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
    R.drawable.image000880,myOptions);
    paint= new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
    mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);

   private void drawpoint(ImageView imageView,float x,float y, int raduis){
    myOptions.inDither = true;
    myOptions.inScaled = false;
    myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// important
    myOptions.inPurgeable = true;
//  ArrayList<Point> list= new ArrayList<>();
    canvas.drawCircle(x,y, raduis, paint);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
}
```

Hope this solution will help others who have the same situation

Answer (score 0):

Simple ImageView Descendent class.

```
public class CiclesImageView extends AppCompatImageView {
    private ArrayList<PointF> theDots = new ArrayList<>();
    private Paint paint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    public CirclesImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            drawDot(new PointF(event.getX(),event.getY()));
            return performClick();
          }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        for (PointF pt:theDots)canvas.drawCircle(pt.x,pt.y,5,paint);
    }

    public void drawDot(PointF dotPoint){
        theDots.add(dotPoint);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

This imageView is used the same way you use any other imageView, except if you touch it, it will draw a circle on itself. If you want to draw your own circles, the drawDot(pointF) is public.

Comment: Did you mean that I should create this class? and create an object from this class in the MainActivity?

Comment: Yes. Are you familiar with creating descendents of Objects?

Comment: If you mean by creating descendants of Objects " Oriented Object Programming", the answer is yes of course

Comment: The problem is the function `rect.contains(x,y)` takes an int as a type for arguments but the points should be floats, not int and What AttributeSet??

Comment: @abdou_dev 
The AttributeSet is null if the class is used inside the code. Android will fill in an AttributeSet if this class is inflated from an XML file. I use the Android Studio previews sometimes, and any View type should have a Context and an Attribute Set in the constructor to make sure the preview works.. 

When I run into problems with float and int, I generally typecast around it. If I have a float x and need an int x, the quick solution is a float typecast as an int   (int)x.

Comment: Ok, I will try this but try to change p.x to p.getX() and p.y to p.getY()

Comment: I created that class, Can you tell me what should I write in the MainActivity?

Comment: @abdou_dev I'm sorry, I think I've mis-understood your problem and have been giving you some bad advice. I saw this as a problem painting directly onto Bitmaps and then loading the ImageView with the bitmap. My suggestions lead to overriding the ImageView itself, and deal direclty with the imageViews canvas, through overriding the onDraw() method. It bypasses dealing with the whole bitmap and works directly with whatever canvas happens to be in the ImageView. Although it can work, it's not a good answer, and gets off topic.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work for me. Can you give me a solution? My question is very simple .. I need to draw multiples points ( circles with raduis<5) on imageView with Android Studio.

Comment: @abdou_dev Ok. I've updated my above answer with a new CirclesImageView class. It behaves, and is used, exactly the same way you use any other Imageview. The only thing this one does, is draw a circle wherever it is touched. It demonstrates drawing on an ImageView.  Variations on this basic method is how I draw all over all my ImageViews.

Comment: Thanks @Ken Bourrows, I solved my problem and I posted the solution.